# ASP.NET MVC can't find my controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a UserController with a Reset method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Resets the current user context.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Reset()
{
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.ActiveCaseID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.ActiveEventID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.CompanyID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.ConnectionString); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.ImpersonateUserToken); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.LoginID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.LoginName); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.MultiSystem); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.ServerName); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.SystemID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.UserID); } catch { }
    try { IAppContext.ClientStateManager.RemoveValue(CookieName.UserName); } catch { }

    LogSecurityEvent(SecurityLogType.InvokedReset);

    return Content("Reset Completed");
}
```

For some reason however this method (or any other) is not being found (I get a 404 error) when I navigate to the appropriate URL, e.g. `https://localhost:31503/User/Reset`. I don't have an SSL certificate on this PC, but the web app does work on my other PC and I don't have one there either unless I set one up a long time ago and forgot about it; I don't have access to that PC right now to check and I wouldn't even know where to look. If I go to `http://localhost:31503/User/Reset` instead, the app just hangs for a while and then I get a "the connection was reset" browser error. I don't see any exceptions being swallowed when I attach a debugger and set it to break on all .NET exceptions.

Here's my `RouteConfig` class - nice and simple, though I don't know much about routing, it doesn't look very complicated...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

edit: oh, some relevant piece of context: the User/Reset action was "working" (at least, displaying the intended message) this morning, but the actual login was not; it was giving me a blank page. When I attached a debugger, I found an exception was being swallowed in a class called `AppContext`, which kept track of, among other things, a database connection string:

```
public string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
            {
                object raw = ClientStateManager.GetValue(CookieName.ConnectionString);
                if (null != raw)
                {
                    _connectionString = raw.ToString().FromEncryptedBase64();
                }
            }
            return _connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

So if the cookie does not exist, the app can't find any connection string and crashes when it tries to connect to the database! I have no idea how this was working before; seems to me it would be impossible to have any new users log in. I then added these lines after the `if` statement to fix it:

```
else
{
    _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Root.Properties.Settings.myapp_configConnectionString"].ConnectionString.FromEncryptedBase64();
}
```

However now I'm just getting all these 404 errors everywhere. Here's the relevant line from the web.config:

```
<add name="Root.Properties.Settings.myapp_configConnectionString" connectionString="(an encrypted connection string is here)" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

`FromEncryptedBase64` is simply an extension method that takes a base 64 string, decodes it, and then applies a decryption algorithm to it; it's a way to safely store connection strings in the web.config without having to store them in plaintext.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Core? 4.x?

Comment: Could you include full controller class, please? (without other methods)

Comment: This should probably not be a GET method...

Comment: it's context based, so you'd need the session token

Comment: Full UserController class? Oh boy, that file is huge... not sure how it wound up that way!

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.5.1.

Comment: I don't know why Reset is a GET method, but it's not really referenced anywhere in the application itself - rather it's more for debugging purposes as sometimes the cookies can get "stuck" when switching between various web apps that I work on. If i try to access the app after not using it for a while and it crashes or freezes for no apparent reason, I go to /User/Reset and that usually clears things up. This time it didn't and even /User/Reset is broken. Maybe I'll try clearing my cookies for this site in my browser?

Comment: Session token? Hmm. I'm not even logged in. But if I navigate to /User which should take me to the Index method where I can log in, I get the same issues on that path instead.

Answer (score 0):

My version comment was so I could address your SSL cert, as there's a built-in tool for Core (maybe 4.x as well, but I haven't used that in a while).

You likely just need to add a specific route because this method doesn't require an `id` like the default route requires. You can do this one of two ways:

Option 1

```
// add an explicit route
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserReset",
            url: "User/Reset"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Option 2

```
// attribute based routing in the controller
[HttpGet]
[Route("User/Reset")]
public ActionResult Reset()
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I manually added the route in the controller, built the solution, and navigated to `http://localhost/31503/User/Reset`, and... still the same 404 error. Could this be some sort of MVC configuration issue where I don't have some necessary component installed somewhere so it's not being recognized as an MVC app? I swear it was loading this morning though but only the reset, not the actual login, so I made a change to load the database connection string from the web.config if there is no cookie containing it since that was what was crashing on the login...

Comment: It looks like it's `[HttpRoute("User/Reset")]` in .NET 4. Whether or not it's available depends on your setup for the MVC/Web API version, etc. If you don't have attribute routing enabled, use Option 1. [Here's an example of setting up attribute routing.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api-and-mvc-4/) It's a bit easier in .NET Core, as it's built in.